# Destructing [] vs {}

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am confused between destructing. 
I am using React in it we do

```
const [ books, setBooks ] = useState([{a:'v'}]
```

and

```
const {books} = useContext(BookContext)
```

So why cant i

```
const [books] = useContext(BookContext) // or
const { books, setBooks } = useState([{a:'v'}]
```

Because both return values and we are destructing them ? How is one different from other ?

Comment: one destructures an array, the other destructures object properties

Comment: `console.log()` what `useState` and `useContext` return. You need to understand why we use destructuring first. It's similar to doing: `const state = useState([])` and `const books = state[0], setBooks = state[1]`

Comment: It's by definition.  useState returns an array, useContext returns the context object (with the relevant properties set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mozilla org destructuring hacks](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/)

lhs type = rha type

What I mean from above is
`const [a, b, c] = [some array]; const {a, b, c} = {some object};`

And not the other way round object properties can be destructured only by `{}` and array properties by `[]`

Comment: You *can* do array destructuring using curly braces. Eg: `const { 0:first, 1:second, length:length } = [1,2]` will get the 2 items and the length of the array

Comment: Only if you are using objects the wrong way out... I don't blame it but yeah you can do it, but object is not meant to be used like that... And I clearly mentioned properties of object, and `0` or `1` clearly are not properties. And on a note type of array is object.

Comment: This is not a link to MDN - it's a different page by Mozilla

Comment: fixed the description

Answer (score 4):

To understand this, let's dive into how `arrays` and `objects` destructing work.

Assume we have two functions `returnsArray()` and `returnsObject()` which returns `['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3']` and `{ a: 'Item 1', b: 'Item 2', c: 'Item 3' }` resp.

**How can we extract values from the `returnsArray()` which returns `['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3']`?**

1. Without destructing:

```js
const tempArray = returnsArray();

const variable1 = tempArray[0]; // Will be 'item 1'
const variable2 = tempArray[1]; // Will be 'item 2'
...
```

2. With destructing:

```js
const [variable1, variable2] = returnsArray();
```

You can clearly observe that destructing reduces the number of lines and makes the code more legible.

Note that the `variable1` and `variable2` are the custom variable names.

**How can we extract values from the `returnsObject()` which returns `{ a: 'Item 1', b: 'Item 2', c: 'Item 3' }`?**

1. Without destructing:

```js
const tempObject = returnsObject();

const attribute1 = tempObject.a; // which is equal to 'Item 1'
const attribute2 = tempObject.b; // which is equal to 'Item 2'
...
```

2. With destructing:

```js
const { a, b } = returnsObject(); // if you want to the variable names as 'a' and 'b' or

const { a: attribute1 , b: attribute2 } = returnsObject(); // if you want to give custom 
// variable names for the attributes 'a' and 'b'
```

You can clearly see that destructing reduces a lot of unwanted code and makes it more legible.

**Now let's look at what will happen when we interchange both?**

```js
const [variable1, variable2] = returnsObject();

// above line literally translates to:
const tempObject = returnsObject();

const variable1 = tempObject[0]; // will be undefined
const variable2 = tempObject[1]; // will be undefined
```

Since we can not access the object's attributes by `tempObject[0]` & `tempObject[1]`, both the variable values will be `undefined`.

Similarly,

```js
const { variable1 , variable2 } = returnsArray();

// above line literally translates to:
const tempArray = returnsArray();

const variable1 = tempArray.variable1; // will be undefined
const variable2 = tempArray.variable2; // will be undefined
```

since `tempArray` doesn't have any attributes named `variable1` & `variable2`. Both of those values will be `undefined`.

#### In your case, `returnsArray()` is `useState()` and `returnsObject()` is `useContext()`.

Answer (score 1):

useState returns a tuple i.e. an array like structure with different types of values. [More reading on tuples](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_tuples.htm)

```
const [a, b] = ["some string", 2]
// a = "some string", b = 2
```

useContext returns an object.

Answer (score 1):

Main reason is because Array are sorted and objects are not.

When you destruct result of `React.useState(5);` you actually destruct value that looks like `[5, x => value = x]` (it does much more actually but for purpose of this answer let's assume it looks like this). Keys of this array are `0` and `1` (`array[0] === 5` `(array[1](2), array[0] === 2)`). So if use want to use object destructing on this value it'd look like `const { 0, 1 } = React.useState(5)` but you can't create variable in JavaScript which name starts with or is `number`.

When you try to destruct object `{ language: 'JavaScript', age: 25 }` you don't know which property goes first. The one which is declared first (language) or maybe the one what is alphabetically first (age)? So you can't expect from language to deduct which value you think should be first.

Answer (score 0):

Descruct with `[]` when operating on an array, use `{}` to destruct when operating on an object:

```
const arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
const [ a, b, c ] = arr; 

// a is 10
// b is 20
// c is 30

const obj = { foo: "hello", bar: "world" };
const { foo, bar } = obj;

// foo is "hello"
// bar is "world"
```